# Why TCP/IP server with listening port in java not working

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have written a code in java to interface my computer with a transmitter a transmitter device, with a communication board already implemented and ready to connect via TCP/IP to any server with a specific address IP (say 192.168.2.2) and listening to a specific port number (say 4000).

I followed the exact strep how to create a server side application in Java offering a that listening port, so that I can connect to that transmitter.
I don't understand why when I try to debug the code, it blocks a the line `clientSocket = serverSocket.accept()`, and throws a timeout exception.

Could someone help me find out where the error might be in my code?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            //Declares server and client socket, as well as the input and the output stream
            ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            PrintWriter out;
            //BufferedReader in;
            BufferedReader in;


            try{

                InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.2.2");

                //Opens a server socket on port 4000
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4000) ;

                //Sets the timeout
                serverSocket.setSoTimeout(30000);

                System.out.println("Server has connected"); 

                //Create a connection to server
                System.out.println("Server listening connection from client ....");

                //Listens and waits for client's connection to the server
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                // Creates input and output streams to socket
                out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                //Reads response from socket
                while((in.readLine())!= null  ){
                    System.out.println ( in.readLine() );
                }

                System.out.println ( "Closing connection ....");

            //Terminates connection
            clientSocket.close();   
            serverSocket.close();

            System.out.println("Connecton successfully closed");                
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could someone help me find out where the error might be in my code?

There is no error in your code that could cause this problem. Clearly you haven't configured the device to connect to this server correctly, or the device isn't running, or it isn't connecting, or there is a firewall in the way. Investigate that.

However:

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.2.2");
```

What is this for? It isn't used.

```
System.out.println("Server has connected");
```

This is simply not true. The server *hasn't* connected. At this point all it has done is create a listening socket.

```
while((in.readLine())!= null  ){
```

Here you are reading a line and throwing it away.

```
    System.out.println ( in.readLine() );
```

Here you are printing every *second* line, having thrown every odd line away. The correct way to write this loop is:

```
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Note also that this server will service exactly one client and then exit. There should be a loop around everything from `accept()` to `clientSocket.close()`, and if there are multiple devices it should start a new thread per accepted socket to handle the I/O.

Comment: Thanks  so much for you help ! Actually the there was a firewall in the way blocking the connection. I turned it off and now the device is able to  connect to the server. many thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

You specified timeout of 30 seconds, didn't you? :

```
serverSocket.setSoTimeout(30000);
```

So after 30 seconds, no matter whether stopped in debugger or running, this will timeout and throw exception.

Comment: yeah I did specify 30 seconds.  But the problem is that even without the timeout line . It just stopped at the same  line  and did not continue .

Comment: @GerkoFord yeah, well accept is a blocking call. I don't know what you're expecting?

Comment: I know, it is a blocking call. But as I explained in the question, if the server is really listening on that port, as per the manual of the transmitter , it should automatically connect to server. But it is not the case. By the way, a socket has been  done in Matlab and works well, meaning, the transmitter is really functioning as the stated in its manual. But I don't understand why it is not working in Java.

Comment: So, can you show the code from matlab? It could be UDP instead of TCPor you need to swap bytes in port value (4000 will become 40975) as it was common in lower level languages. But definitely the server code is correct regarding the setup part.